# Jquery clickable body but not content

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set my homepage's body element clickable in a click through campaing (there's color background image in body), but when I click on anywhere at the site, this click is executed, of course. How can I remove this click event from my content (#page) to avoid click-throguh in content.

HTML source:

```
<body>
  <div id="page">Content goes here. This div is centered, 980px width element
  </div>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$('body').click(function() {
  window.open('http://example.com');
  return true;
});
```

Thanks,

DanyG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( 'body' ).click( function ( e ) {        
    if ( this === e.target ) {
        // the BODY was clicked directly; do your thing
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vk7rz/

Inside the above click handler, the `this` keyword references the "owner" of the click handler which is the BODY element, and the `e.target` property references the top-most element that was clicked. If both references refer to the same element that means that the BODY element was clicked directly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it work funcionally in all browsers I've tried. Thanks for all answers to everybody.
DanyG

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
$('body:not(#page)').click(function() {
  window.open('http://example.com');
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Clicking on the `#page` element should not execute `window.open` but it does in your case...

Answer (score 1):

You have to manualy disable clicks on body childrens

http://jsfiddle.net/2hyW5/1/

```
$('body>*').click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The body element is the parent for all of your pages elements. If you click any part of the page you are ultimately clicking the body. I'm not sure you can accomplish that using this technique. If I am incorrect about this, somebody feel free to explain it better.